# Why do we train martial arts?

Tags: brazilian-jiu-jitsu, aikido, judo, jujutsu

I've been doing some serious thinking on WHY I am doing martial arts. I can't get it out of my mind and that's all I've been thinking about.

This all happened after a trip to Japan and Australia with my Sensei. He introduced me to a huge number of Senseis from different arts like Aikido, Karate, Jiu-Jitsu, Iado, etc.

After having long, serious, and enlightening chats with them, I found that in the end, they would always ask me WHY I am practicing it. All my answers basically have a hole in them, and now there is a hole in my heart.

Below are my answers and the senseis' replies:

> **Me:** Because it is exciting and I love to spar and meet new people.
>
> **Them:** What happens when you get old or when you are unable to spar. You would not get the excitement that you used to have. Would you abandon your art after that?
>
> **Me:** Condition my body, make me strong.
>
> **Them:** What happens when you get to your highest level of strength and fitness? Do you then stop progressing? Do you stop practicing since you have achieved your goal?

There are many more answers which I have given, but could not recall.

I've been practicing it for all these years, basically for self defense and general fitness. The competition parts also make it exciting for me. Philological-wise, I've been trying to understand and live by their way.

How can I overcome this dilemma?

Comment: I voted to close because your question is too broad and invites discussions. The latter is very much not supported by SE sites. This would make for an interesting conversation but this Q&A site is not the place for it.

Comment: I agree with Sardathrion. Interesting question, but as it is too broad and basically a list question. Better suited to be discussed on [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2353/the-dojo)

Comment: I think with a few nudges this question would do fine in the Q&A format. Nigel has posed a specific question about the purpose of training. Instead of getting on a high horse about proper questions, **EDIT THE QUESTION** so it fits the guidelines.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann: I honestly cannot find a way to ask "Why do you train" in a way that would fit SE without being a list of things, too broad, and so personal that no one answer would fit more than a few people unless platitudes are given.  If you think you can, go for it!

Comment: @Sardathrion Have you read [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)? This question inspires long "why" and "how" answers that share experiences. It's more than just social fun. This is a good subjective question. SE is *not* supposed to be knee-jerk opposed to this kind of question.

Comment: This is a very opinion based question that is impossible to answer objectively.  More than that, it's something that's going to be a personal journey, and a question you'll ask yourself time and again throughout your martial arts career.

Comment: @DaveLiepmann - I've read good/bad before, and I think this misses on points 5 and 6. It's close, but I don't think it's a good subjective question.

Comment: @JohnP That's fair. In general I think many users aren't even aware that there are perfectly fine subjective questions.

Comment: There are good subjective questions, as there can be good list questions. I agree, many people on SE have not read the good/bad essay.

Comment: Give your answer, not the one you think they want. On that note, my answer is always "to get to know my limits and to evolve my understanding of what that question means". Basically I'm saying that I want to improve myself, but I don't think I quite know what that means, and can only get a clearer picture as I mature in my art.

Comment: @jacefarm Why did you edit this obviously bad question?…

Comment: @Sardathrion It is still a matter of record and part of this forum - tidying up. See ["Is closure the end of the road for a question?" and "When are closed questions eligible for deletion?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10583/271738). If it is to die, maybe it should then be deleted, yes?

Comment: @jacefarm Your edit did nothing to improve the question: it is still off topic and in my not so humble opinion unsalvageable. We need more good questions, not pointless cosmetic changes to bad one. That said, I do appreciate your keenness. 'Nuff said.

Comment: @Sardathrion My edits **have improved** the post ([grammar, spelling, fix minor mistakes as the post ages](https://martialarts.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/edit)). Curation is a worthwhile agenda, and is encouraged in all SE forums, including this one. It is an intention that reflects upon forum quality, is freely given by the community, and should be nurtured, not disparaged. It's been a while, but perhaps the OP would be nudged, might improve, or request that the question be opened. If unsalvageable, then it should be deleted, and our time would not have been wasted thus...

Answer (score 2):

These Japanese "masters" sound like losers.

When you're too old to compete, you can still spar and  give back to the art by coaching.

When you're too old to spar, you can still hang around the gym to give pointers and be friendly. You can still train to be fit and in condition. The idea that you'll reach your pinnacle of fitness and then need to quit is not just wrong, it's nihilist nonsense. Physical culture is not about reaching a goal and then going back to the couch. It's a lifestyle.

Anyway, I doubt these pseudo-martial-artists have come within a dozen miles of reaching the peak of their physical or martial abilities.

Have they squatted and done gymnastics, achieved a split, written a book on the nuances of *nage-no-kata*? Do they know nothing of *shugyo*?

It sounds like these guys are soft, and they want you to train soft too. Reject that. One can train hard well in the martial arts into one's forties and fifties, and can continue to achieve new physical feats into one's sixties and seventies.

These guys want you to give up on that and train like you're already ninety, eschewing hard sparring and rigorous training not because it's impossible but because they don't like the feeling of hard work. I bet they want to play with kata and wrist locks and other non-competitive, physically undemanding soft training, and they want to brainwash you into doing the same. Don't listen to them.

Comment: Losers, maybe.  Trolling, most definitively: instead of a goal, I believe they were pointing to the road. Finding a goal is easy but walking the path is hard.  Which is more or less what you are saying...  Although, I am not sure you answered the question -- whatever the question was.

Comment: Your prejudices are showing. If I had a student that I asked that question and they respond "I love to spar", that indicates a more superficial view, and I would also ask "What happens if you couldn't spar any more?". I think they are inviting him to see beyond his current somewhat myopic viewpoint. Also, if you have someone that truly enjoys what you call "soft" training, is that a bad thing? Is it only really martial arts training if you're throwing around small cars and running into walls to toughen yourself?

Comment: @JohnP Try using "soft" training techniques in a real life scenario. Many people believing in "soft" training are ignorant and are lying to themselves. I agree with Dave Liepmann.